# c# error on saving data from datagridview to Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I have a problem on saving an items in the datagridview together with their orderno on the mysqldatabase, I've tried to use this codes:

```
 connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        connection.Open();
        command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            sql = "insert into Item values('" + torderno.Text + "','" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["itemno"].Value + "');";
            command = new MySqlCommand(sql, connection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            //Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

        }
        connection.Close();
```

after I run it their is an error appeared which is this one:
"Column count doesn't match value count at row 1"

what should I do?
do you have an idea whats the problem of this?

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.  Might want to look into using parameterized queries.  As for the error, it's simply telling you that you're not providing the correct number of columns to insert into that table.  Look at the table definition to see the columns it expects.

Comment: Yeah I allready checked it, it has 2 columns which I can only stored two data on it!
why is this happing?

Comment: Does your table have an index column (UID) which is a primary key that is autoincrement or something?  If it does (and I think it has to in order to work with the datagridview, but I work mostly with WPF so it might be different) then you must list the column names and then the values in your insert statement (as in answer below).  If your table truly only has the two columns then I think it is poor database design, and without an index/primary key SQL may not work as you expect.

Comment: The error now is changing! it says "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order values('1','1002')' at line 1"
what do you think sir!

Comment: @SpideyEudzAragon: "order" is a reserved word, you can't use it as an object name unless you enclose it in back-ticks.

Comment: order is just my replacement of my item there cause I also have mistaken on declaring a table name on it :) but sir I think I get it now..
thank you for all the advises and concerns sir I appreciate it so much! it is such a big help!!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your table and see how many columns are there,
in you insert query the number of values must equal the columns or you should write columns name (except auto incremental column)
such as following:

```
insert into tblName(colName1,colName2,...) values (val1,val2,...);
```

or

```
insert into Item VALUES (vlueForCol1,valueForCol2,valueForCol3,...);
```

in other words your table has more columns than you are inserting into.

take a look at [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

Comment: I believe this should be a comment

Comment: I change its style now sir and copy the codes you've given and now the error change which is this one "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order values('1','1002')' at line 1"

Comment: @SpideyEudzAragon you don't need copy and past my given code that is just an example, please make sure about columns and read that link .

Comment: Yeah I know its an example what I mean is I copied ur example which is I edit it ofcourse and apply it....
thnx for the example sir! appreciate it sir.